# How do i get this CASE statement right in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm getting ORA- 00936 missing expression error near > symbol while trying to run this request :

```
SELECT contract_ref_no,
       component
FROM   some_table
WHERE  Contract_ref_no = '123'
AND    component = 'ABC'
AND end_date
   (CASE WHEN NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') = 'N' 
    THEN 
       > greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                l_contract_vdate)
    ELSE                 
       >=
     greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                         l_contract_vdate)  
    END)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you precise ? Where are you stuck ? What is the issue ? Please clarify your question

Comment: i am getting ORA- 00936 missing expression error near > symbol

Comment: Ok, I will make an answer

Comment: The *problem* here is, you **can't** *push down* the logical operator (`>`) into the `CASE`, you must use e.g. `end_date > (CASE..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit reformulation based on the rules of Aristoteles you may write

- you allways want the `end_date` is *greather than* your `greatest` *expression*

OR

- in the *else* case `NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') != 'N'` thay may be *equal*

*Predicate*

...

```
AND (
end_date  >  greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate), l_contract_vdate)
OR
NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') != 'N'  and  end_date = greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate), l_contract_vdate)
)
```

which is the same as the predicate below that more resembles your original intention

```
....
AND (
NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') = 'N' AND end_date > greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),l_contract_vdate)
OR
NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') != 'N' AND end_date >= greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),l_contract_vdate)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your case statement to -

```
SELECT contract_ref_no,
       component
  FROM some_table
 WHERE Contract_ref_no = '123'
   AND component = 'ABC'
   AND CASE WHEN NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') = 'N'
                 AND end_date > greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                                         l_contract_vdate) THEN
                 1
            WHEN end_date >= greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                                      l_contract_vdate) THEN
                 1
       END = 1;
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is when l_neg_esn_allowed = N then end_date > greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                                         l_contract_vdate else end_date >= greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                                      l_contract_vdate
note - end_date is one of the columns

Comment: I have compared the end_date column with condition. Check the query.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query that you write have syntax error.

The `THEN > something` can't work : Superior to what ? Same with the `>=` after, superior or equals to what ?

So, you should have something like `column > value`, such as you will have `column = value` or `column LIKE 'my val'`.

Finally, I suggest you to use this code:

```
SELECT contract_ref_no,
       component
FROM   some_table
WHERE  Contract_ref_no = '123'
AND    component = 'ABC'
AND end_date
   (CASE WHEN NVL(l_neg_esn_allowed,'N') = 'N' 
    THEN some_date > greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                l_contract_vdate)
    ELSE some_date >= greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                         l_contract_vdate)  
    END)
```

Comment: Earlier the code was just SELECT contract_ref_no,
       component
FROM   some_table
WHERE  Contract_ref_no = '123'
AND    component = 'ABC'
AND    end_date >
                     greatest(nvl(l_conv_eff_date, l_contract_vdate),
                              l_contract_vdate)

Comment: Now when my l_neg_esn_allowed is N then it shd be default validation else >= validation